# how to kill python program with exact program name?

Tags: python, linux, kill

i wanted to kill a python program using linux command pkill -f "a.py", but this also kills other program with similar name.

for example:
if i want to kill a.py using command `pkill -f "a.py"`. It also kills a program with name ab.py

Comment: dot is a special regex symbol, you should escape it: 'a\.py'

Comment: i have a problem with argument also:

if i try pkill -f  "a.py 2" it kills a.py 25 {note:2 and 25 are the arguments passed}

Comment: Both full commands satisfy your pattern. It should be `pkill -f 'a\.py 2$'` (escape dot to avoid fitting any unexpected characters, add dollar sign to clarify that pattern ends with 2 and the following 5 is not part of it)

Comment: What's the context here? Really, you shouldn't be killing individual processes on production infrastructure at all -- instead, tell your operating system's service manager to manage them, and then you just tell it when you want a service started or stopped (`systemctl start myprogram.service` / `systemctl stop myprogram.service`, and then it's configurable how that operates -- if you want it to kill everything in the controlgroup, or only the main PID, or some combination of the two -- as well as configurable if your service automatically starts on boot, which other services start first, etc)

Answer (score 1):

First of all, your problem as it is stated originally is not reproducible. I created `a.py` and `ab.py` with infinite loops, then I ran `a.py 2` along with `ab.py` in two terminals and then `pkill -f 'a\.py'` killed one of the two processes, just as expected. Same happens if I name second file `b.py`. And actually the same happens even if I forget to escape the dot.

As for clarifications in comments, you're simply using an incorrect pattern.

Both full commands `a.py 2` and `a.py 25` satisfy your pattern. Therefore it should be `pkill -f 'a\.py 2$'` (notice the escape dot to avoid fitting any unexpected characters, add dollar sign to clarify that pattern ends with 2 and the following 5 is not part of it)

reference `man pkill`:

> -f, --full The pattern is normally only matched against the process name.  When -f is set, the full command line is used.
>
> OPERANDS
>
> pattern
>
> Specifies an Extended Regular Expression for matching against the process names or command lines.

Important part here is that your argument behaves like a regex, not like a simple string pattern.

Answer (score 0):

How about using `ps` to see the proces?

Then you can see the process command name like `~path python3 a.py` and its running time.

Thus you can identify the process you want to kill and simply do `kill process_num`